# ¿jsPFD y Html2canvas necesitan de acceso a internet, y estas son gratis?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jspdf, html2canvas

Tengo una pequeña duda en relación a las librerías jsPDF y Html2cavas ¿estas necesitan acceso a internet o no? ya que en el desarrollo que tengo no puedo utilizar nada que consuma un servicio externo, también necesito saber si estas 2 son completamente gratis o se debe de pagar algo por utilizarlas

Comment: Si revisas los repositorios de esas librerías podrás ver con qué licencia trabajan y sus requerimientos.

Answer (score 0):

Las instalas con el gestor de paquetes de Node npm que se comunica con  un repositorio en linea es libre el acceso se requiere internet para instalar el paquete Luego queda el codigo en tu programa y no requiere descargar mas nada
[tutorial npm](https://www.freecodecamp.org/espanol/news/node-js-npm-tutorial/) ya no requiere internet Algo totalmente distinto a CDN (Content Delivery Network) que si requiere internet para ejecutarse si a eso te réferis con tu pregunta

```js
npm i html2canvas 
npm i jspdf
```